# Is it possible to assign the local variable after calling a global function with the same name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have defined a function foo:

```
def foo():
    print('hi')
    return np.array([1,2,3])
```

I want to use the result it provides inside another function called 'execute', and assign that result to local variable having the same name 'foo':

```
def execute():
    foo = foo()
    foo -= 1
    print(foo)

execute()
```

The above will result in "local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment".

Now if I use **global** inside my execute function:

```
def execute():
    global foo
    foo = foo()
    ...
```

It will work but after calling it once it will rewrite the global function, which isn't what we want.

Comment: We could use `foo_` or `_foo` or whatever the hell, for a local variable. But that makes it more confusing in my case. Suppose, I don't want to use any other name.

Comment: Cool, it's working! I guess you may want to post it as answer.

Comment: You could do away with the intermediate variable altogether: `print(foo() - 1)`

Comment: I think it's being voted down because you dismiss the obvious and best approach (i.e. avoid the name collision in the first place) without any justifiable reason. Votes are not "toxic", they're simply a measure of the usefulness of a question/answer - usefulness not necessarily to the O.P. but to any future readers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `globals()` directly:

```py
def execute():
    foo = globals()["foo"]()
    foo -= 1
    print(foo)
```

But really I think you should avoid the name conflict in the first place, which would be less confusing to readers:

```py
def execute():
    foo_result = foo()
    foo_result -= 1
    print(foo_result)
```

Comment: The first way will not work, since the presence of `foo = temp` makes `foo` into a local variable _at function definition time_.

Comment: No it's actually great. No confusion for me. However I don't think the intermediate variable option will work though.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, it would perhaps be best to rename the function to `get_foo()` or `make_foo()` or `generate_foo()`, to disambiguate from the object `foo` it returns.

Comment: Generally yes. Not if you export the module, will make unnecessarily long names.

Comment: Well, you just demonstrated why it is _necessary_ to have a different, 4-character-longer name, to avoid colliding with the useful object name `foo`.